# Loading contents from parent window to child window

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I am working on spring web application, i have one of the jsp page which contains a table and below that table i have `iframe`. Now my problem is, i want to set `tr` content which is inside `iframe` from my `parent window` (i.e containing jsp page). I planning some thing like this,

**Inside iframe:**

```
<tr id="trID"></tr>
```

**In Parent jsp:**

```
$('#trID').load('some thing i need');
```

How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

try this...

Create a div inside the  `td` with `id #divID` and upload content by following code

```
$('#divID').html('some thing i need');
```

Comment: my requirement is kinda different, i found the solution myself. Anyway thanks for answering.